# What is TableItem in BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I Was following this tutorial about creating a custom Adapter and ListView

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_3_-_customizing_a_listview%27s_appearance/

But when i added the code it says " The Type or namespace TableItem could not be found on this code when it extends base Adapter

```
public class HomeScreenAdapter : BaseAdapter <TableItem> {
        List<TableItem> items;
        Activity context;

        public HomeScreenAdapter(Activity context, List<TableItem> items)
            : base()
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
        }
```

What is TableItems is Just a class with the list of items I want to add anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it working thanks for everyone's help

for other people this is what i done

Create a class called TableItem and add:

```
    public class TableItem
{
    public string whatever;


    public TableItem(string whatever,....){

        this.whatever = whatever;


    }
```

and just create a List Instance and pass the text you want to display

Answer (score 0):

That's probably been taken from an example. The data you want to view is often passed to the adapter. In this case it seems this data is of type `TableItem`.

You would pass your data into the adapter. This can be app specific or something basic as `string`.

Comment: Yes its an example from the Xamarin website can i create a class called TableItem and create a List Instance of it?

Comment: Sure. Why not just try it? Learning by coding.